# How to calculate definite integral when boundary is a limit?

Tags: integral-equations

```
Integrate[Log[x]/(1-x)^2,{x,eta,Infinity}]
```

The conditions are `eta>0`, and `eta->1`, how to incorporate the conditions?

Comment: If you want to integrate along a continuous path, going clockwise halfway round the pole at `x = 1`, then evaluate `Assuming[0 < eta < 1 && 0 < eps < 1 - eta, Integrate[Log[x]/(1 - x)^2, {x, eta, 1 - eps, 1 + I eps, 1 + eps, Infinity}] // Simplify]`. Use `1 - I eps` to go anticlockwise halfway round the pole.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Please consider posting an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Assumptions` (as per documentation).

Also note that it does not converge under those conditions. If you are looking for a principal value you can do

```
ii = Integrate[Log[x]/(1 - x)^2, {x, eta, Infinity},
  Assumptions -> 0 < eta < 1, PrincipalValue -> True]

(* Log[-(eta^((eta/(-1 + eta)))/(-1 + eta))] *)
```